# finding angles 0-360 in arctan

Tags: python, math

I need help with a math issue:

I need to get the angle from 0 until 360 degrees but this code gives the angle between -90 until 90 degrees:

```
N = math.cos(β * (math.pi / 180)) * math.tan((f + ω) * (math.pi / 180))
N2 = math.atan(N) * (180 / math.pi)
```

I want to N2 change between 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: replace `math.atan` with `math.atan2`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`atan2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan2) like so

```
import math
math.atan2(-0.1, 0.1) + math.pi
```

The problem is `atan` does not know which quadrant you are in, while `atan2` does as it accepts an x and y coordinate as input.

If you compute `atan(y / x)` you need to switch things around so you compute `atan2(y, x)` instead. I can't understand how that relates to your example exactly.